# Нужно убрать в начале каждой строки лишний пробел

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import sys
num_steps = int(sys.argv[1])

for x in range(1, num_steps+1):
    print (" " * (num_steps - x), "#" * x )
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит "лишний"?

Comment: Всезнающий Google такое показал: *x = x.lstrip()* - Если слева. С двух сторон - *x.strip()*

Comment: по шестой строки видно, что есть лишний пробел слева ) его нужно убрать

Comment: подсказка: сравните `print('', 'a')` и `print('', 'a', sep='')`

Comment: понял, спасибо большое

Answer (score 7):

`print(x, y)` вставляет пробел по умолчанию между `x` и `y`. Поэтому пробел остаётся даже когда `x` у вас пустой. Замените запятую на `+`, чтобы как одну строку печатать: `print(x + y)`.

---

<sup>для людей, привлечённых сюда заголовком вопроса — не имеет отношения к задаче в самом вопросе:</sup>

Можно использовать `s = s.lstrip()`, чтобы убрать все пробелы в начале строки:

```
>>> ' \na \n'.lstrip()
'a \n'
```